# Unity3D, Roll a Ball works with no errors, 'player' sphere passes through Walls

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Player sphere will not collide with walls.

Unless Rigidbody/Constraints/Freeze Position/Y-axis is 'on', Player rolls on the ground plane for a bit then passes through the Ground plane and falls ad infinitum.

```
public class BallControl 
    : MonoBehaviour 
{ 
    public float speed; 
    private Rigidbody rb; 

    void Start () 
    { 
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
    }

    void FixedUpdate () 
    { 
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal"); 
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical"); 
        Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);
        rb.AddForce (movement * speed);
    } 
}
```

Any remedy would be most welcome. Thanks

Comment: Any signs of effort? Where's your code, what is causing this behaviour, what have you tried to solve it, what ... anything?

Comment: As a complete novice, I followed the instructions as given in the tutorial. I have spent 4 days reading answers to related questions. I am convinced it is something simple like an on / off switch altering the sphere to a solid :

Comment: As a complete novice in psychic powers and mind reading, I have no clue what have you done so far. **Maybe** if you would put your code in the question it would make a difference...

Comment: I apologise for my ignorance. I have spent 4 days tortuously reading answers to related questions.  using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class BallControl : MonoBehaviour {

 public float speed;

 private Rigidbody rb;

 void Start ()
 {
  rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
 }

    void FixedUpdate ()
 {
  float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
  float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");

  Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);

  rb.AddForce (movement * speed);
 }
}

Comment: @AtomicD. don't put code in comments, you should update your question and put the code there (like m.rogalski did for you already). Also go re-watch the video on adding the walls, you likely forgot to add a collider to the walls

Comment: You should make sure that the sphere,walls and ground have colliders.

Comment: Thank you m.rogalski, Scott Chamberlain, itay_421 & Cristiano Soleti. I had the wrong kind of collider on my walls. I choose box collider...NO, No, No! When I removed the Box collider and replaced it with a mesh collider it worked! Kudos thank you for lateral thinking (Literally)!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit messy. 
Though , it's normal that if your sphere rolls out the ground , it will go down for ever.
If your ball doesn't collide your "Wall" which should be a gameobject with at least a box collider on it, it means that your "ball player" doesn't have a sphere collider on it.